# Show datetime now in input (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have input with strong type

Here is code

`<input type="text" name="dateTime" value="@Model.DateTime"/> Date <br/>`

I try to show DateTime.Now in this input by default with this code

`@{ DateTime dateTime = Model.DateTime.Year > 2000 ? Model.DateTime : DateTime.Now;}`

But it not works and I have this error

[image]

How I can show DateTime.Now in input?

Comment: It's nullable. DateTime.Value.Year.

Comment: Always use code rather than image.

Comment: using c# 6 features all you need is a ?, i.e. `@{ DateTime dateTime = Model.DateTime?.Year > 2000 ? Model.DateTime : DateTime.Now;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `DateTime?` which is **nullable** type so you would need to access it via `Value` property of it the actual value like:

```
Model.DateTime.Value.Year
```

But you would need to make sure that it is not `null` as well like:

```
if(Model.DateTime.HasValue)
```

otherwise it will throw exception at run-time.

You can refactor it to something like:

```
@{ 
    DateTime dateTime = (Model.DateTime.HasValue && Model.DateTime.Value.Year > 2000) 
                         ? Model.DateTime.Value 
                         : DateTime.Now;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your `Model.DateTime` is `nullable` type and you are trying to assign `Model.DateTime` value to `dateTime` variable. So, `null` cannot be assigned to a `not-nullable` type.

You need to check if it is null or not then you can compare the year with 2000 like below

```
@{ 
    DateTime dateTime = Model.DateTime.HasValue?( Model.DateTime.Value.Year > 2000 ? Model.DateTime.Value : DateTime.Now) : DateTime.Now;
}
```